# how to group rows with like cells in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, filtering, grouping

Sorry for the remedial question but for some reason I can't wrap my brain around this.

I have a group of rows with 3 cells each. Using Jquery I need to

1. filter out all rows which don't have cell number 3 equal to a variable "large" in this case
2. group the remaining rows by the value of the 2nd cell (color)
3. add a group header with the value of the color (black, white, red, etc..)
4. any blank groups should not be shown

Easier to look at my example...

```
var dogSize = "large";
```

show only large dogs, group by color of dog with header.  if header has no items, do not show it.

```
<tr class="dogs">
    <td class="name">Mindy</td>  <td class="color">black</td>    <td class="size">big</td> </tr>
<tr class="dogs">
    <td class="name">Mandy</td>  <td class="color">black</td>    <td class="size">little</td></tr>
<tr class="dogs">
    <td class="name">Tina</td>  <td class="color">spotted</td>    <td class="size">medium</td></tr>
<tr class="dogs">
    <td class="name">Sandy</td>  <td class="color">brown</td>    <td class="size">big</td></tr>
<tr class="dogs">
    <td class="name">Harry</td>  <td class="color">brown</td>    <td class="size">little</td></tr>
<tr class="dogs">
    <td class="name">Sam</td>  <td class="color">brown</td>    <td class="size">medium</td></tr>
<tr class="dogs">
    <td class="name">Larry</td>  <td class="color">white</td>    <td class="size">big</td></tr>
<tr class="dogs">
    <td class="name">Chico</td>  <td class="color">black</td>    <td class="size">small</td></tr>
```

Normally I'd bang my head on this until I figure it out but at this point I'm struggling and don't know how to achieve this.  Thanks a ton for the assist!

Comment: Why don't you make it easy on yourself and use of the [numerous table plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations) on offer?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You can use the `:contains()` pseudo-selector to select only the rows that have a certain size and you can use `.sort()` to sort the table rows into a new order:

```
var dogSize = 'medium',
    $table  = $('table'),
    $TRs    = $table.find('tr');

$TRs.filter(function () {
    return ($(this).children('.size').text() != dogSize);
}).hide();

var arr = $TRs.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aText = $(a).children('.color').text(),
        bText = $(b).children('.color').text();
    if (aText > bText) {
        return 1;
    } else if (aText < bText) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
$table.empty().append(arr);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C399w/2/

Comment: Thanks Jasper!  Any idea how to group the results now?  I figured that would be the most challenging.

Comment: @CeeMoney Check-out my update. You can use the JavaScript `sort()` function to sort the table rows, store the new order in an array, and then replace the HTML of the table to that of the newly sorted rows.

Comment: @CeeMoney Here is a demo that may be more like what you're looking for; you can click on dog sizes to only show that size: http://jsfiddle.net/C399w/3/

Comment: Ultimately I have to show them grouped together and the groups divided. 
The real life scenario is that this is a left hand panel for a website with a list of links.  Those links need to be grouped and shown by topic, then displayed.

Comment: The variable, dogSize in the exammple, is actually coming from a selected value of a jquery ui tab.   So the user is choosing a tab with a specific subject and there's data on this left-hand panel that I'm trying to group and filter.  That doesn't really change anything, just trying to give you a better view of things.